# Windows hook gets called only once

Tags: windows, qt, dll, hook

Good afternoon. I'm writing a global mouse hook. Everything seems to work just fine except that the hook is called only for the first mouse event.
Some code:

```
// Dll defined function
    extern "C" Q_DECL_EXPORT LRESULT MouseProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        qDebug() << "MouseProc";
        return TRUE;
    }

// Application code
    ...
        hLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("ServerHook.dll"));
        HOOKPROC hookAddr = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(hLib, "MouseProc");
        if (!hookAddr) {
            qDebug() << "Invalid hook proc " << GetLastError();
        }
        if ((WinInputHook::hookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(
                    WH_MOUSE, hookAddr, hLib, 0))
                    == NULL) {
            qDebug() << "Invalid hook handle " << GetLastError();
        }
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The hooking you'r installing (WH_KEYBOARD) ["installs a hook procedure that monitors keystroke messages" and not the mouse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Indeed you are right. At the same time, that is not the case, because for key events it procs only one time also.

Comment: Please take care that your DLL does not get released by the system.

Comment: How could I accomplish that? DllCanUnloadNow?

Comment: You should not accomplish this, otherwise (it could be your case) your hook won't get invoked. DllCanUnloadNow - is only exported by COM-aware images. You must take care that the process your LoadLibrary is invoked in, continues to run.